# Command to open new shell and block

Tags: zsh, aur

My AUR helper runs a command to open the package files for inspection before proceeding to build and install. This needs to block, because after the program exits, the AUR helper will ask me to confirm whether to proceed.

Currently I use ranger, which works reasonably well. However it would be more convenient to open a new shell in that directory. That way I can use my regular CLI tools to inspect the build files, and when done, exit the shell with `exit` or Ctrl+D and end up back at the AUR helper prompt.

How can I launch a shell like zsh, so that it starts in a given working directory, and also blocks the original process?

Comment: `(cd "/path/to/dir" && zsh)` would block ordinarily, but the real question is: how does the AUR helper pass the filename/directory to the program it launches? You might need to write a wrapper script that takes a filename as argument, runs `dirname` on it to get its directory, then `cd`s into that directory and runs `zsh` from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have since realized that `ranger` will already do this: Pressing `S` will drop you into a new shell in the current directory. When you do `Ctrl+D` in that shell, you go back to `ranger`, and then you can do `q` to quit ranger and go back to the AUR helper.